# Access file thread-safe in Java

Tags: java, thread-safety, file-handling

I'm really puzzled how little I can find on the web about this simple problem. I have build a webpage using Servlets and furthermore I'm using the quartz library to trigger cronjobs.
I'm using the `Files.copy` method to handle the data.

In one of the cronjobs I download a file and copy it, in another one I copy this file, and on the webpage I display the file.
How I prevent problems like accessing a file while it gets replaced?

My first idea was to create a class which has a static lock object which the other classes have to lock/sync before writing data. Does this make sense?

Comment: To my understanding, if a file is Open/Used by something, nothing else can open it again?  Unless it is saved/closed..

Comment: Have a look at file locks. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html . A static lock object (probably `new Object()`, right?) won't prevent cross-process access to the files.

Comment: The static lock solution would only work if you are assuming that the concurrent access occurs from threads coming from the same Java JVM, otherwise you need to lock at the shared resource, i.e., the file

Comment: I'd suggest to stay away from runtime locks. If you have a pipeline for a file, use specific file name pattern to hide the file from the next step until the file is ready for it. For example, in 1st cronjob save file with temp extension. After the file is stored completely, rename if to a name, which makes the file visible for the 2nd cronjob... Also, in 1st cronjob you can find all previously created temp files not renamed for 2nd job to cleanup not successfully stored ones (by a crash/unexpected stop etc)